# swift multipart post with 2 or more base64encoded image in json param fails

Tags: json, swift, image, base64, multipartform-data

Well, the request holds many params and one of them is a json string.

The problem: if the json param has more than 1 image in it (as shown below), the server side received post simply does NOT have it (the json param is not there in the post). Nevertheles, the rest of the params in the post are there in good shape (not shown in this example).

json parameter debugged:

THIS WORKS:

```
[{"title":"A","image":""},
{"title":"B","image":"HERE BASE64ENCODED IMAGE"}]
```

THIS WORKS TOO:

```
[{"title":"A","image":""},[{"title":"B","image":""},
{"title":"C","image":"HERE BASE64ENCODED IMAGE"}]
```

And these are the json params content that will be ignored in the server received post (each post has only one json param):

DONT WORK:

```
[{"title":"A","image":""},
{"title":"B","image":"HERE BASE64ENCODED IMAGE"},
{"title":"C","image":"HERE BASE64ENCODED IMAGE"}]
```

DONT WORK ALSO:

```
[{"title":"A","image":"HERE BASE64ENCODED IMAGE"},
{"title":"B","image":"HERE BASE64ENCODED IMAGE"}]
```

Every image is at most 900kb.(in my debug they maked in total 1.3MB)

EDIT: here the request:

```
let url:NSURL = NSURL(string: url)!
var request = URLRequest(url: url as URL)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
request.cachePolicy = URLRequest.CachePolicy.reloadIgnoringCacheData
request.setValue("multipart/form-data; boundary=\(boundary)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")
```

My doubts are focused in the multipart-form body, here the code i am dealing with so far:

```
var body = Data()
for (key, value) in parameters {
    body.append("--\(boundary)\r\n")
    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"")
    if key == "json" {
        body.append("\r\n")
        body.append("Content-Type: text/json")
    }
    body.append("\r\n\r\n")
    body.append("\(value)\r\n")
}
body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
return body
```

EDIT 2: (following Dale's comment) This didnt fix it also.

```
    body.append("--\(boundary)")
    body.append("\r\n")
    body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"params\"\r\n")
    body.append("Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\(boundary2)")
    body.append("\r\n\r\n")

    for (key, value) in parameters {
        body.append("--\(boundary2)")
        body.append("\r\n")
        body.append("Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"\(key)\"")
        body.append("\r\n\r\n")
        body.append("\(value)\r\n")
    }

    body.append("--\(boundary2)--\r\n")
    body.append("--\(boundary)--\r\n")
```

EDIT 3: How the json param is constructed (@OOPer):

```
let image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: self.getPath() // String extension
let data = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.4)
let strBase64 = data.base64EncodedString()
var post1 = [String:Any]
post1["title"] = "AA"
post1["image"] = "\(strBase64)"

let aPosts = [[String: Any]]()
aPosts.append(post1)
aPosts.append(post2)... etc

// later on
let data = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: aPosts)
let jsonParam = NSString(data: data, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8.rawValue)
let param["json"] = jsonParam

let parameters = [String : String]()
parameters.update(other: param)
```

thx

Comment: You don't seem to have defined boundary in the data. You need something like "Content-Type:multipart/mixed;boundary=\\(boundary)". See http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc1341/7_2_Multipart.html

Comment: You are not showing what the content of `parameters` is in your code. And your EDIT2 code is very likely wrong. Most servers cannot detect `multipart/mixed` data contained in `multipart/form-data`. (Though, it depends on how your server is configured.) What is `parameters`?, please show it.

Comment: @OOPer: Param in Post is ignored ONLY when contains more than 1 base64EncodedString (image) in an array, which is JSONSerialization'ed. (example above). As said, the rest of params are received in Server ok. I am thinking somehow a chars conflict in it? THX!

Comment: @OOPer: The param in question:  --Boundary-8C50599D-A8EB-486F-B3C3-803E1612F2B9

Content-Disposition: form-data; name="jsonLOG"


[{"created":"2017-07-27 11:01:14","image":"\/9j\/4AAQSkJgAAAAAAA6ABAAMAAVmZ2h...(ETC)"},{"created":"2017-07-27 11:01:21","image":"\/9j\/4AAQSkZJRgABAQAASABIAAD\/4QBYRXhpZgAATU0AKgAAAAgAAgESA...(ETC)"}]

Comment: Also: The json param is validated... A chars conflict anyhow? mm.. but 1 base64enconded image in json WORKS, but 2 already dont...

Comment: In your code `parameters` is used in `for (key, value) in parameters`, so it must be a Dictionary or an Array of tuples. `[{"created":"2017-07-27 11:01:14","image":...` is an Array of Dictionaries, so you must be constructing `parameters` somewhere else.

Comment: @OOPer: parameters is [String : String] ...

Comment: Please show how you construct it in your question with **code**.

Comment: @OOPer: edit 3 added. Thx!